# Delete from table where something in another table is true

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `users` and `bans`. I want to delete from bans any rows where the `user (ID)` in that row hasn't been active for `30 days` or more. I have a column called `last_session` in my `users table` saved as a `timestamp(as an integer)` of their last connection, and an column in my `bans` table called `banned_user_id`, which is just the `ID` of the `banned user`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
Delete b.* from bans b, users u 
where b.banned_user_id = u.ID 
and u.last_session < subdate(now(),30)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Prabin's answer. I prefer using joins.

```
delete b
from bans b
inner join users u on
  b.banned_user_id = u.id 
where 
  u.last_session < subdate(now(),30)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one only deletes records from the bans table, as specified in the question:

```
delete from bans
where banned_user_id in (
  select user_id
  from users
  where last_session <= subdate(now(), 30)
)
```